In my Unity project AdMob ad appears and disappears but area remains click able
Hey I have recently integrated AdMob in my Unity game project when I open my app in my phone it show me ad for 0.5 second and then disappears but the area remain clickable on clicking it behave like ad but not showing.
Note: This is working perfectly in my editor but making issues in real device.
I have created a Ad Manager project with this code
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Banner : MonoBehaviour
{
    private BannerView bannerView;

    void Start()
    {
        // Initialize Google Mobile Ads SDK
        MobileAds.Initialize(initStatus => { });

        // Load and show the banner ad
        StartCoroutine(ShowBannerWithDelay(3f));
    }

    IEnumerator ShowBannerWithDelay(float delay)
    {
        // Wait for the specified amount of time
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);

        // Show the banner ad

        // Create the banner ad at the bottom of the screen
        bannerView = new BannerView("XXXXXXXXX", AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Bottom);

        // Create the ad request
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
        bannerView.LoadAd(request);

    }

    public void HideBanner()
    {
        if (bannerView != null)
        {
            // Hide the banner ad
            bannerView.Hide();
        }
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        // Destroy the banner when the object is destroyed
        if (bannerView != null)
        {
            HideBanner();
            bannerView.Destroy();
            bannerView = null; // Clean up the reference
        }
    }
}


It re loads ad on game restart :)
I have tried to implement AdMob ads but im getting hidden ads.

Is anything calling HideBanner from the outside (as it is public)?

In general instead of waiting for magic 3 seconds .. shouldn't you rather wait for the Initiate callback to finish and also check if initialization even was successful?

@derHugo May be its happening because of test ads? And this is working perfectly in editor it just causing issues in real apk, I have checked it is initialising properly in Debug Log

So have you checked the log off the real apk as well?

@derHugo Yes I did it is completely fine I used log cat it is showing ad is initialising
